# Is functional component cause memory issue?

Tags: reactjs

In functional component, we declare function inside component. It creates new function in every render. But in class component, it is added in the component prototype and reuses that function. Is it cause any memory related issue?

```
function Text({name,value}){
   function onChange(e){
         onChange(name,e.target.value);
   }
   return <input name={name} type="text" onChange={onChange}/>
}

class Text extend React.Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this)
  }
   onChange(e){
     this.props.onChange(this.props.name,e.target.value)
   }
  render(){
    return <input type={text} onChange={this.onChange} value={this.props.value}/>
  }
}
```

Above approach is ok or have to follow any other best practice?

Thanks

Comment: I want to know that as well, waiting anyone giving answer or discuss

Comment: functions are Objects in JS , so they are passed by reference and hence there should not be a memory issue as they are being passed around the same way like classes

Answer (score 0):

A closer version of React class component to your functional component:

```
function Text({name, value, onChange}){
   function onChange(e){
         onChange(name,e.target.value);
   }
   return <input name={name} type="text" onChange={onChange}/>
}
```

is not your component in your question, but this:

```
class Text extend React.Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
  }
  render(){
    function onChange(e){
         this.props.onChange(this.props.name,e.target.value);
    }
    return <input type={text} onChange={onChange} value={this.props.value}/>
  }
}
```

Declaring something new inside `render` is normal; I often see people create variables to perform filtering on props or state before rendering, and the difference in performance is not significant; in your case, if `onChange` function inside functional component is simple, then it's not a big deal.

Alternative solution would be using PureComponent instead of functional component:

```
class Text extend React.PureComponent{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this)
  }
   onChange(e){
     this.props.onChange(this.props.name,e.target.value)
   }
  render(){
    return <input type={text} onChange={this.onChange} value={this.props.value}/>
  }
}
```